# Is there a CPAN module for converting seconds to English?

Tags: perl, time, cpan, intervals, time-format

Is there a CPAN module that can convert a number of seconds to a human-readable English description of the interval?

```
secToEng( 125 ); # => 2 min 5 sec
secToEng( 129_600 ); # => 1 day 12 h
```

The format isn't important as long as it's human-readable.

I know that it would be trivial to implement.

Comment: A lot of people think working with dates and times is trivial, and this is simply not the case. You've done the right thing by looking for an existing module :)

Comment: @ocharles: You're definitely right about date handling being hard. I think this case is quite easy though :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Perl v5.9.5, the modules Time::Seconds and Time::Piece are part of the core Perl distribution. So you can use them without installing additional modules.

```
perl -MTime::Seconds -e 'my $s=125; my $ts=new Time::Seconds $s; print $ts->pretty, "\n"'
# 2 minutes, 5 seconds

perl -MTime::Seconds -e 'my $s=129_600; my $ts=Time::Seconds->new($s); print $ts->pretty, "\n"'
# 1 days, 12 hours, 0 minutes, 0 seconds
```

You can also use stuff like `$ts->weeks`, `$ts->minutes`, etc.

Comment: "1 days" is a bug: the singular is "day". Please *perlbug* this.

Answer (score 14):

It turns out that [Time::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Time-Duration/Duration.pm) does exactly this.

```
$ perl -MTime::Duration -E 'say duration(125)'
2 minutes and 5 seconds
$ perl -MTime::Duration -E 'say duration(129_700)'
1 day and 12 hours
```

From the synopsis:

> **Time::Duration - rounded or exact English expression of durations**
>
> Example use in a program that ends by noting its runtime:
>
> ```
> my $start_time = time();
> use Time::Duration;
> # then things that take all that time, and then ends:
> print "Runtime ", duration(time() - $start_time), ".\n";
> ```
>
> Example use in a program that reports age of a file:
>
> ```
> use Time::Duration;
> my $file = 'that_file';
> my $age = $^T - (stat($file))[9];  # 9 = modtime
> print "$file was modified ", ago($age);
> ```

Answer (score 10):

[`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) can be used:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime;
use Lingua::EN::Inflect qw( PL_N );

my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch( 'epoch' => 0 );
$dt = $dt->add( 'seconds' => 129_600 );
$dt = $dt - DateTime->from_epoch( 'epoch' => 0 );

my @date;
push @date, $dt->days . PL_N( ' day', $dt->days ) if $dt->days;
push @date, $dt->hours . PL_N( ' hour', $dt->hours ) if $dt->hours;
push @date, $dt->minutes . PL_N( ' minute', $dt->minutes ) if $dt->minutes;
push @date, $dt->seconds . PL_N( ' second', $dt->seconds ) if $dt->seconds;

print join ' ', @date;
```

### Output

```
1 day 12 hours
```

Comment: I have to admit that the “xxx(s)” notation is a personal pet peeve of mine. If they can do anything, computers *should* be able to count and distinguish `1 day` vs `2 days`. :( Note that prefix notation as in `Days: 1` doesn’t have this issue.

Comment: However, just "$x day" . ($x > 1 ? 's' : '') is a sloppy way of handling this. If you always use translation libraries to build your strings, this comes for free.

Comment: You only fixed the 'easiest' part of the problem, converting seconds to something else.

Comment: *[MichielB](http://stackoverflow.com/users/114904/michielb)*: The answer addresses **just** the problem in the question. With [`DateTime`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime), other conversions are easy as well.

Comment: Lingua::EN::Inflect is an interesting solution to the pluralization problem.  https://metacpan.org/module/Lingua::EN::Inflect

Comment: *[Schwern](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14660/schwern)*: I have just updated my answer to include [`Lingua::EN::Inflect`](https://metacpan.org/module/Lingua::EN::Inflect). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't able to find such code a while back, so I wrote these two routines.  The second sub uses the first and does what you are looking for.

```
#-----------------------------------------------------------
# format_seconds($seconds)
# Converts seconds into days, hours, minutes, seconds
# Returns an array in list context, else a string.
#-----------------------------------------------------------

sub format_seconds {
    my $tsecs = shift;

    use integer;
    my $secs  = $tsecs % 60;
    my $tmins = $tsecs / 60;
    my $mins  = $tmins % 60;
    my $thrs  = $tmins / 60;
    my $hrs   = $thrs  % 24;
    my $days  = $thrs  / 24;

    if (wantarray) {
        return ($days, $hrs, $mins, $secs);
    }

    my $age = "";
    $age .= $days . "d " if $days || $age;
    $age .= $hrs  . "h " if $hrs  || $age;
    $age .= $mins . "m " if $mins || $age;
    $age .= $secs . "s " if $secs || $age;

    $age =~ s/ $//;

    return $age;
}

#-----------------------------------------------------------
# format_delta_min ($seconds)
# Converts seconds into days, hours, minutes, seconds
# to the two most significant time units.
#-----------------------------------------------------------

sub format_delta_min {
    my $tsecs = shift;

    my ($days, $hrs, $mins, $secs) = format_seconds $tsecs;

    # show days and hours, or hours and minutes, 
    # or minutes and seconds or just seconds

    my $age = "";
    if ($days) {
        $age = $days . "d " . $hrs . "h";
    } 
    elsif ($hrs) {
        $age = $hrs . "h " . $mins . "m";
    } 
    elsif ($mins) {
        $age = $mins . "m " . $secs . "s";
    }
    elsif ($secs) {
        $age = $secs . "s";
    }

    return $age;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for supplying some code. I was mostly interested in knowing whether there's already such a CPAN module out there, or if one should be written.

Comment: The question was not 'Please write me a sub'.

Comment: I didn't write a sub for him. I shared some code I wrote for myself years ago. Thought that would be a friendly thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

The [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) modules are what you want.

[DateTime::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aDuration) and [DateTime::Format::Duration](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime%3a%3aFormat%3a%3aDuration) will do what you need.