# Convert seconds to days, hours, minutes using Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to take *control of the output* generated in seconds using **perl**. I would like to show the time (in seconds) in the form of days, hours, minutes and seconds to make it **human readable format**.

**Code**

```
my $start = time;
<some other perl codes>
my $duration = time - $start;
print "Total Execution time: $duration s\n";
```

**Output** is 311052 s

**Required Output** is 3 days 14 hours 24 minutes 12 seconds

**Note:** I am new to Perl. Before you flag this is as duplicate, I have done my research. I have gone through *all* the stackoverflow where *similar solutions* were discussed, none helped. My code is very small. What could be the few line changes that could be added.

Comment: Links to name a few: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16019848/how-to-add-hours-minutes-seconds-in-perl, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20049665/cant-control-how-hours-minutes-seconds-are-formatted-using-perls-datetimefo, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545664/is-there-a-cpan-module-for-converting-seconds-to-english, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545664/is-there-a-cpan-module-for-converting-seconds-to-english

Comment: What's wrong with the last one you mention?

Comment: @JB - Adding just those modules will help? What changes should I add in those few lines of code?

Comment: Going through half of the relevant StackOverflow answers won't help if you don't allow it to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use the [`Time::Piece`](http://metacpan.org/module/Time::Piece) and [`Time::Seconds`](http://metacpan.org/module/Time::Seconds) modules, which will do all of this for you

In this program I have simply added pi days onto the current date and time to get a representative duration. You will, of course, use an actual time

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds qw/ ONE_DAY /;

my $start = localtime;
my $end = $start + int(355/113 * ONE_DAY);

my $duration = ($end - $start)->pretty;
print "Total Execution time: $duration\n";
```

#### output

```
Total Execution time: 3 days, 3 hours, 23 minutes, 53 seconds
```

Comment: Your code worked perfectly. Small issue here, my execution time is random. Sometimes it generates **311052 s** sometimes only **17653 s** sometimes **24 s**.

Comment: @arka.b: Why is that a problem?

Comment: Yes, because my execution time varies. *Say* my execution ran for **12 hours 14 seconds** it will still show me **3 days, 3 hours, 23 minutes, 53 seconds**

Comment: @arka.b: My second paragraph says *"In this program I have simply added pi days onto the current date and time to get a representative duration. You will, of course, use an actual time"*. You need to call `localtime` again to get the actual end time. I didn't imagine that all of your execution times were exactly 3.14 days!